# Why is my activity crashing when hitting the home button?

Tags: android, cursor, nullpointerexception, listactivity, runtimeexception

At this point I'm quite frustrated. I've been researching this for a few days and cannot even isolate anything beyond a cursor problem. I am extending ListActivity and using startManagingCursor(newcursor) in the OnCreate method. Here is the code (the database is already filled) that runs and crashes upon hitting the home button:

```
private void loadAlbums() {
    try {
        newcursor = mDbHelper.getAlbumTitlesCursor();
        dbalbumadapter = new AlbumListCursorAdapter(this, newcursor);
        setListAdapter(dbalbumadapter);
        }
    catch (SQLiteException s) {
        newcursor = null;
        fetchalbums = new FetchAlbumsTask().execute();
        }
    current_view = ALBUMTITLE_VIEW;
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
02-03 13:41:42.379: WARN/dalvikvm(340): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-03 13:41:42.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.skip.ngRCv2/com.skip.ngRCv2.ngRC}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.skip.ngRCv2/com.skip.ngRCv2.MusicLibraryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3227)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3272)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1880)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.skip.ngRCv2/com.skip.ngRCv2.MusicLibraryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3227)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3174)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:176)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchStop(LocalActivityManager.java:572)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onStop(ActivityGroup.java:79)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1169)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3797)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3224)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     ... 11 more
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3808)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3224)
02-03 13:41:42.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     ... 18 more
```

There is a NullPointerException at Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3808), which seems to come from this method in Activity.java even though I can't cross-verify that with the line number:

```
final void performStop() {
     if (!mStopped) {
         if (mWindow != null) {
             mWindow.closeAllPanels();
         }

         mCalled = false;
         mInstrumentation.callActivityOnStop(this);
         if (!mCalled) {
             throw new SuperNotCalledException(
                 "Activity " + mComponent.toShortString() +
                 " did not call through to super.onStop()");
         }

         synchronized (mManagedCursors) {
             final int N = mManagedCursors.size();
             for (int i=; i<N; i++) {
                 ManagedCursor mc = mManagedCursors.get(i);
                 if (!mc.mReleased) {
                     mc.mCursor.deactivate();
                     mc.mReleased = true;
                 }
             }
         }

         mStopped = true;
     }
     mResumed = false;
 }
```

I have tried closing and deactivating my cursor in the OnStop method as well as setting the list adapter to null. I was under the impression that none of this was necessary when letting the activity manage the cursor as I indicated. I am passing the cursor to my custom adapter but none of the examples I've found do any managing inside the adapter.

If you can help me at least narrow down what is throwing this exception, I would be grateful!

Comment: sounds like you may let the cursor be managed by the activity but somewhere you set the cursor null which cause the NPE?!

Comment: Yes, it was a null problem when calling startManagingCursor().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is the right rev, line 3808 corresponds to:

[[ I know its not the official android source, but the line number lines up]]

http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java?r=12#3808

```
mc.mCursor.deactivate();
```

As far as I can tell, mc cannot ever be null. ***It seems that `mCursor` (which is final) can be `null` only if a `null` cursor was passed into `startManagingCursor()`.*** I captured my notes before for others to confirm this.

***Can you log your cursor is just before you pass it into `startManagingCursor()`?*** I'd be curious what the last occurrence of that message before the crash says.

You have this line when there's a sql exception:

```
newcursor = null;
```

I wonder if that's getting into the `startManagingCursor()` call.

---

Notes:

- startManagingCursor() creates a `ManagedCursor`:

http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java?r=12#1549

```
public void startManagingCursor(Cursor c) {
    synchronized (mManagedCursors) {
        mManagedCursors.add(new ManagedCursor(c));
    }
}
```

- `ManagedCursor` sets `final` field mCursor:

http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java?r=12#647

```
private static final class ManagedCursor {
    ManagedCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
        mReleased = false;
        mUpdated = false;
    }

    private final Cursor mCursor;
    private boolean mReleased;
    private boolean mUpdated;
}
```

- All the internal calls to `startManagingCursor()` are guarded, e.g.:

http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java?r=12#1465

```
if (c != null) {
    startManagingCursor(c);
}
return c;
```

Comment: Wow, that totally helped fix my problem. Thanks! Perhaps I'm naive (definitely a novice here), but I just figured that I could just call startManagingCursor() before I set the value, meaning it was null by default. This totally fixed my problem! So I guess the question is should I not use the same cursor variable for different queries? And if I can, I should call startManagingCursor() each time it's changed?

Comment: That and `stopManagingCursor()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Start your app in a debugger, set an exception breakpoint on NPE and then see where it is bailing out.

Should give you an idea what is going on.